# using toString() for a type variable in C#

Tags: c#, variables, types, tostring

I am facing a problem in my C# code. I would like to convert a variable of type T to a string, using the toString() method. I have overridden this method for my own types, and it is important for the variable I use to be generic, because it can take values of multiple types. I have tried using a cast to Object, but it returns an error saying that

```
 'object' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.
```

This is the line of code:

```
 T stud;
 students += (stud as Object).toString()+"\n";
```

Comment: ToString(), not toString(). C# is case sensitive.

Comment: It should be ToString() ... probably

Comment: The method is `ToString` not `toString`. You also don't need the cast to `Object`. You also might want to consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ToString(); C# is case sensitive.
Also, as already explained in the comments, you don't need to use the `as Object` conversione because every class in C# has the ToString() method defined because every class derive from `object`

However, if the code above is exactly your code, you have another problem.

The variable stud of type T is not initialized anywhere and using

```
(stud as Object).ToString()
```

will result in a null reference exception

Comment: I have initialized it, I left that part out. And thanks, works just fine now

Answer (score 4):

This is because `System.Object` defines method [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the capital `T`. Change the case to fix the problem.

Note: the code that concatenates strings with `+=` is often inefficient. If you need to concatenate a small, fixed, number of strings, use `string.Format("{0}\n{2}", firstString, secondString)`. If you need to concatenate a larger number of strings, use a `StringBuilder`, or a `string.Join` method.